# Retrieving Portfolio Item objects using Ruby Toolkit for Rally REST API

Tags: ruby, rest, rally

I am having a bit of trouble accessing portfolio items using the Ruby toolkit. The examples show how to retrieve almost every object EXCEPT for portfolio items. Following the general trend, my assumption is that one would use the following to retrieve them, given that project objects do not provide references to them:

```
rally = RallyRestAPI.new(:base_url => @base_url, :username => @user_name, :password => @password)

rally.find_all(:portfolio_item).each{
   |pi| print pi.formatted_i_d + "\n"
}
```

However, that does not seem to be the case, as I receive the following error:

```
<OperationResultError>Not able to parse artifact type: portfolioitem</OperationResultError>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you use webservices API version is 1.26 or higher - Portfolio Items were first introduced into the object model starting with 1.26. I believe the Ruby REST API defaults to Webservices API 1.17 if not specified explicity. You can explicitly define it as follows:

```
    rally = RallyRestAPI.new(:base_url => @base_url, :username => @user_name, :password => @password, :version => 1.33)
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you for the clue. I should have considered this, but I made the assumption that it would default to the latest version. Do you know why they haven't done so?

Comment: I think it hasn't changed so that existing code doesn't break - i.e. it's been defaulted that way for a long time, and changing that default to a newer version could break working code.

Comment: Well, I would think that they would build it so that it would be more backwards compatible. At least, it should include the version that can work with their newest introduced objects. Unfortunately, I suppose clients using the older APIs just aren't pushed to update very frequently.

Comment: Perhaps a potential future build of the ruby rest api gem will update the default webservices version to a higher level and document that well, in order to avoid surprises.